# ATMega input buffer

Tags: atmega, multiplexer, atmel, input, atmega328p

What happens if a AVR ATMega controller is doing something else when a input arrives on one of the serial ports? Does it has some sort of input buffering?

I was thinking of using ATMega328 or simalar to a RS232 multiplexer with white-list setences filter. The RS232 ports are going to operate on 4800 Baud, 9600 Baud and 38400 Baud

Answer (score 1):

The ATMega 328 USART has two RX buffer registers. Data always goes in to these registers before anything else happens. This means the CPU doesn't even know data is being received until the RX buffer has some data in it.

What happens after that... well, that depends.

Assuming: Interrupts are globally enabled, and you have the USART Rx Int enabled.

If the CPU is executing the main body of code (doing something else), then as soon as data is available on the USART Rx buffer, it will jump to your USART Rx interrupt handler.

If the CPU is executing in an interrupt, the USART Rx interrupt will wait to execute. There are some ways around this waiting, but the default behavior is that pending interrupts wait for actively running interrupts.

If the CPU just finished an interrupt, the USART Rx interrupt might be serviced next or later depending on what other interrupts are waiting to be serviced. The AVR has fixed interrupt priorities (See table 16.1 in the ATMega 328 manual), which ever has the lowest interrupt request number has the highest priority and will execute next.

hope that helps.

Comment: Is it possible to connect external RX buffers to the ATMega328? Because I need least 5 RS232 ports,

Comment: @BufferOverflow Such buffers don't exist, but you could attach external UART tranceivers. They will cost you many times more than the AVR, however. For example, you could attach four [XR16L570](https://www.exar.com/content/document.ashx?id=361), or one [ST16C554](https://www.exar.com/content/document.ashx?id=1293)

Comment: @BufferOverflow Although you can certainly shoehorn the extra RS232 functionality in (with sufficient effort), I would check to see if a more sophisticated chip can help you out.

Comment: @BufferOverflow I would recommend using an XMEGA series part; these can have up to 8 hardware UARTs.  This will make the interfacing job much easier.

Answer (score 1):

The USART peripheral of the Mega AVRs has double buffering of the received serial data; The receive shift register and USART I/O Data Register 0 (UDR0) are the two buffers.

[image: Cropped from 24.3. USART 0 block diagram]

This allows the processor to read data from UDR0 while the next data byte is already being shifted into the receive shift register. When a stop bit is received, the data contained within the receive shift register will automatically be transfered into UDR0, and the USART Receive Complete flag (RXC0) will be set.

You can receive data as fast as it arrives by always reading the received byte from UDR0 as soon as the RXC0 flag is set. This can be done with polling:

```
setup_usart_for_asynchronous_data_at_desired_baudrate();
//receive 64 bytes
uint8_t rxBuffer[64];
uint8_t rxBufferIndex = 0;
while(rxBufferIndex < 64)
{
    while (!(UCSR0A & (1<<RXC0)));  //wait until a new data byte has been received
    rxBuffer[rxBufferIndex] = UDR0; //store the byte in the buffer
}
```

If you want to process things in the background while receiving data (instead of just waiting for data to arrive frame by frame), you can do the same with interrupts. You can set up an interrupt to fire every time a new frame of data is transfered into UDR0, and then move the received data into a buffer within the code of the interrupt service routine.

For more details on the USART peripheral refer to the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_datasheet.pdf)

If you need to receive more than one asynchronous serial bus simultaneously, you will have to poll the IO ports and do some fairly complex processing to extract the data in software.
As an alternative, you might want to consider [I2C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) or [SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus)  communication instead. These buses allow you to connect multiple chips to the same hardware serial tranceiver.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a different Atmel microcontroller, such as an XMEGA series part.  XMEGA series parts can have up to 8 hardware UARTs, making this sort of application quite straightforward.  I would not recommend using software UARTs if you can't rely on only one being active at a given time.

The UARTs on the XMEGA devices work just like those on the ATMEGA devices.  There is a 1 byte deep FIFO on both the receive and transmit side, and transmission and reception can be handled automatically with interrupts.

Here is an interrupt-driven UART driver for XMEGA (and also ATMEGA) series parts: https://github.com/alexforencich/templates/blob/master/xmega.cpp/usart.cpp

Comment: The larger MEGA series parts also have multiple UARTs. The ATmega324p has two, with four on the 1280 and 2560s.